# How is Financial Services Cloud installed into an org as a un/managed package if it uses standard objects?

Tags: financial-services-cloud, industry-cloud

The [documentation describes two ways](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.fsc_admin_packages.htm&type=5) of installing Financial Services Cloud:

- As an unmanaged package
- As a managed packaged

However, having worked on projects with industry clouds being installed such as Health Cloud, Manufacturing cloud and so on, I was able to inspect via the [Object Manager](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.extend_click_find_objectmgmt_parent.htm&type=5) some of the FSC objects, such as [BusinessMilestone](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.financial_services_cloud_object_reference.meta/financial_services_cloud_object_reference/sforce_api_objects_businessmilestone.htm), but I did not find the FSC managed or unmanaged package installed in the [Installed Packages page](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.distribution_installed_packages.htm&language=en_US&type=5).

This led me to a question whether these objects are viewable even though the FSC package is not installed, and also if these objects have standard name (no namespace or custom object suffix), how are they installed?

Perhaps the FSC standard objects now come with the standard Sales Cloud license, but the package installation grants access to it? If that was true, a simple feature license would suffice. I am confused.